# Listing all the files that I have created on a Linux cluster

Tags: files, find

I am working on a Linux cluster that is accessed by many people. I would like to list all the files in all directories that have been created by me. I want to do this because there is a lot of content and many of the directories are quite messy so I would like to keep to cluster clean at least on my behalf. Going manually through all the directories is laborious so I tried to come up with a bash code to do this for me:

```
ls --author -l -R | awk '$5=="my_user_name" {print $0}' | less
```

I execute this from the root directory. What would be a more efficient way of doing this ? Also I am wondering is this kind of code safe to use since I don't have permissions to most of the files on the cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help you,

```
find / -user "your_username" -print
```

That will print all files, directories starting from `/` partition which belongs to you.

Comment: and to make it cleaner, you might append '2>/dev/null' so that you don't see all the "permission denied"